# Can't unbind/detach eventListener set by external script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've run into a problem that I have yet to find a solution for. I'm currently working in a project where I'm needed to re-use already existing components. I have no access to the source of these components and can not change the original files. This means that differing behavior or styling needs to be "overridden" by new files I create.
I'm now running into a problem where a form has a "submit" eventlistener attached to it using jQuery `.on('submit')`.
According to some threads I found, I'm supposed to detach the even using `.off()`, but that does not work. I've tried `.unbind()` as well, but haven't had success. The eventlistener is attached like this:

```
 $(element).on("submit.Parsley", function(e) {
```

So it looks like parsley is being used for the form validation.

What I need to achieve is basically just preventing the attached functions to run. But since my script gets loaded in After theirs, I can't use preventDefault on the submit event.

Any help is very welcome.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Events have to be unbound by the same function they were bound with, so if you don't have access to the originally bound function you can't unbind it.  But if the event was bound with `on`, then try `off()` with no parameters.  You can't unbind individual handlers with `off` if you don't have the original method.

Comment: @Keith
Sadly, that doesn't seem to work either. I've also tried to unbind the events with a timeout, just to make sure that i'm not calling the unbind function too soon. I'm quite at a loss here

Comment: @Keith I'm not really sure what you mean, when you say i need access to the originally bound function. Could you make a small example? It would help me understand the problem better.

Comment: @Keith In jQuery, you can actually unbind all listeners at once

Comment: `$(element).off("submit.Parsley")` doesn't work?

Comment: No, i have tried it, and it does not work either. I'm really not sure what is going on here.
I tried to set up a test page locally (just an index.html and 2 separate js files).
Set an eventListener on the first js file, and used .off() from the second file, and it worked flawlessly. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: @Bergi yep, that's what I said.  But the OP said listener not listeners.  And I though you needed the original function to unbind a single listener.  To be honest not used jQuery for a long time now, so u could be wrong.